# Wrong SASS behavior of HSL function

Tags: css, sass

I've tried to set the color via hsl SASS function:

```
$red: hsl(0deg, 100, 100);
```

It should be Red, or #FF0000, but it compiles into the White color

Comment: If this helps, here are the named colors and all the values you are looking for. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors:_A%E2%80%93F#B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red (#ff0000) equates to

```
hsl(0deg, 100, 50)
```

[**Check it out**](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp)

Lightness is a percentage; 0% is black, **100% is white**